# send a json encoded var via custom field of PayPal Buy Now button

Tags: php, json, button, paypal

The idea is that I have a standard PayPal Buy Now button in my test website. I was able to learn how to pass a single variable to the PayPal payment processing page and get it back in my listener/success page. I do this by introducing a value to the hidden *"custom"* field in the form containing the button. So far no problem.

However, since I need an array of data, not just a single value for a single variable, I am trying to apply JSON ENCODE method to send the data and then use the JSON DECODE method in my success message url. I have three defined variables: $st_id,$selected_mod,$selected_tut.

Sadly, none of them can pass through. How can I make it work? Thanks.

```
    <form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="JKXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php json_encode( array($st_id,$selected_mod,$selected_tut,JSON_FORCE_OBJECT) ) ;?>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
// THE FOLLOWING IS MY CODE IN SUCCESS MESSAGE URL
<?php
$ipn_post_data = $_POST;
    //$st_id=$_POST['custom']; //this works if I use a simple variable than a json encoded array

$posted_json = json_decode($_POST['custom']);
$json_st_id= $posted_json['0'];
$json_mod_code= $posted_json['1'];
$json_tut_id= $posted_json['2'];

echo "Wow! Payment was done.";

echo "Your student ID:&nbsp".$json_st_id."<br />";

echo "Module:&nbsp".$json_mod_code."<br />";

echo "Selected Tutor:&nbsp".$json_tut_id."<br />";

echo "Please save the above information until you will receive a confirmation from us. Thank you."
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you aren't `echo`-ing the JSON encoded array so your `value` attribute will be empty.

Second, you will get nested double quotes for any string values in your array, eg

```
value="[123,"some mod","some tut",16]"
```

You need to properly encode the HTML attribute value

```
value="<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode([$st_id,$selected_mod,$selected_tut])) ?>"
```

Also, I really wouldn't use `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT` (which you were doing incorrectly) with an array.

See http://php.net/manual/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: the following code worked perfectly for me: <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode(array($st_id,$selected_mod,$selected_tut))); ?>"> Thank you very very much! @Phil